# Akka Actors: Handling DB Failures Without Losing Data

Tags: database, scala, akka, actor

**Scenario**
The DB for an application has gone down. This results in any actor responsible for committing important data to the DB failing to get a connection

**Preferred Behaviour**
The important data is written to the db when it comes back up *sometime in the future*.

**Current Implementation**
The actor catches the DBException, wraps the data in a DBWriteFailed case class, and sends the message to its supervisor. The supervisor then schedules another write for sometime in the future (e.g. 1 minute) using system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(...) so that we don't spin in circles too much while waiting for the DB to come back up.

This implementation certainly works but I feel there might be a better way.

- The protocol gets a bit messier when the committing actor has to respond to the original sender after a successful commit.
- The regular flow of messages to the committing actor is not throttled in any way and the actor will happily process the new messages, likely failing to connect to the DB for each and every one of them.
- If messages get caught in this retry loop for too long, the mailboxes of the committing actors will start to balloon. It is important that this data be committed, but none of it matters if the application crawls to a halt or crashes due to excessive memory usage.

I am an akka novice and I am largely inexperienced when it comes to supervisor strategies, but I feel as though I may be able to leverage one of those to handle some of this retry logic.

Is there a common approach in akka for solving a problem like this? Am I on the right track or should I be heading in a different direction?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [Akka Circuit Breaker](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0-RC6/common/circuitbreaker.html) to reduce connection attempts. Instead of using the scheduler as retry queue I would use a buffer (with max size limit) inside the actor and retry those when circuit breaker becomes closed again (onClose callback should send message to self actor). An alternative could be to combine the circuit breaker with a [stashing mailbox](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0-RC6/scala/actors.html#Stash).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Patrik; I wasn't aware the Circuit Breaker existed until you mentioned it. You guys have packed so many goodies into Akka for us :D

Comment: AFAICS stashing doesn't guarantee to preserve message ordering, and database update reordering can lead to the updates being impossible to commit (e.g. tries to insert new version of row before the old one has been deleted, resulting in a primary key violation). I therefore wrote my own alternative to stashing.

Answer (score 1):

**If you're planning to implement full failover in your app**

Don't.

Do not bubble database failover responsibility up into the app layer. As far as your app is concerned, the database should just be up and ready to accept reads and writes.

If your database goes down often, spend time making your database more robust (there's a multitude of resources on the web already for this: search the web for terms like 'replication', 'high availability', 'load-balancing' and 'clustering', and learn from the war stories of others at [highscalability.com](http://highscalability.com/)). It all really depends on what the cause of your DB outages are (e.g. I once maxed out the NIC on the DB master, and "fixed" the problem intermittently by enabling GZIP on the wire).

You'll be glad you adhered to a separation of concerns if you go down this route.

**If you're planning to implement the odd sprinkling of retry logic and handling DB brown-outs**

If you're not expecting your app to become a replacement database, then [Patrik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13910955/51280) is the best way to go.

Comment: Although I like the idea of not having to deal with DB failures when writing my application, they do happen. A particular scenario would be high load on the DB resulting in intermittent connection failures. Making my DB more robust is an excellent solution, but it is a reactive one; future upgrades will not help the users that are currently using the system. Are you suggesting that I fail hard (perform no write) and tell the client to try some other time?

Comment: I assumed the worst and thought you meant to handle hard, extensive database outages. Answer modified.

Comment: Thanks. I completely agree with you that trying to handle extended DB failures within my app will at best be a pain and at worst make my application an unwieldily beast. +1

Comment: The fundamental lesson of distributed systems is that failures are not one-in-a-billion events that can be safely ignored; the more complex your distributed system gets, the more likely you will experience some form of failure in it. And yes, routers do go down and routers do get misconfigured and routers do get supplied with bugs in their firmware, even in 2013.